How to allow dotween to start a tween on the same gameobject while one is already running
I'm trying to figure out how to make dotweens start and merge while one is already happening.
[System.Serializable]
public class CameraSettings
{
    public GameObject CameraFollow;
    public CamerasProperties[] camerasProperties;
    public bool flightMode;
    public float flightSpeed;
    public float timer;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class CamerasProperties
{
    public GameObject Camera;
    public float timeToTravel;
    public Ease easeType;
    public float pauseBefore;
}
public CameraSettings cameraSettings;
GameObject cameraToMove;
private void Start()
{
    cameraToMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCam").gameObject;
    StartCoroutine(DoCameraStuff());
}
int currentNum = 0;
IEnumerator DoCameraStuff()
{
    if (currentNum <= cameraSettings.camerasProperties.Length)
    {
        CamerasProperties cameraProp = cameraSettings.camerasProperties[currentNum];
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(cameraProp.pauseBefore);

        // Create a sequence for the camera movement
        cameraToMove.transform.DOMove(cameraProp.Camera.transform.position, cameraProp.timeToTravel).SetEase(cameraProp.easeType);
        cameraToMove.transform.DORotateQuaternion(cameraProp.Camera.transform.rotation, cameraProp.timeToTravel).SetEase(cameraProp.easeType);

        currentNum++;
        StartCoroutine(DoCameraStuff());
    }
}

The code is above.
I tried using sequences, but it didn't work.
How would I make tweens using DOTween continue when one is starting

https://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php#creatingSequence
Example section

I made a best guess at what I think the functionality should be doing, you can indeed use sequences to fix your issue and simplify the code a little bit. I used this code on my local machine and it worked as intended. Even if it doesn't fully solve your issues hopefully it's a good example of how to use sequences within your code.
To have things happen at the same time in a sequence (like Move and Rotate in your example) you have to Append something first and Join any other tweens and they will happen at the same time. Finally don't forget to actually start the sequence sequence.Play();
private void Start()
{
    cameraToMove = Camera.main.gameObject;
    DoCameraStuff();
}

void DoCameraStuff()
{
    Sequence sequence = DOTween.Sequence();
    for (int i = 0; i < cameraSettings.camerasProperties.Length; i++)
    {
        CamerasProperties cameraProp = cameraSettings.camerasProperties[i];

        sequence.AppendInterval(cameraProp.pauseBefore);

        sequence.Append(cameraToMove.transform.DOMove(cameraProp.Camera.transform.position, cameraProp.timeToTravel)
            .SetEase(cameraProp.easeType));
        
        sequence.Join(cameraToMove.transform.DORotateQuaternion(cameraProp.Camera.transform.rotation, cameraProp.timeToTravel)
            .SetEase(cameraProp.easeType));
    }

    sequence.OnComplete(() =>
    {
        //on complete logic
        CameraStuffComplete("SEQUENCE COMPLETED");
    });
    sequence.Play();
}

void CameraStuffComplete(string message)
{
    Debug.Log(message);
}

Edit: This feels hacky and might not be the best way of doing this, but you can chain sequences like this, and should allow for tween overlap, although I don't know your exact scene setup to test it properly.
void DoCameraStuff()
{
    Sequence mainSequence = DOTween.Sequence();
    for (int i = 0; i < cameraSettings.camerasProperties.Length; i++)
    {
        Sequence camSequence = DOTween.Sequence();
        CamerasProperties cameraProp = cameraSettings.camerasProperties[i];

        camSequence.AppendInterval(cameraProp.pauseBefore);

        camSequence.OnComplete(() =>
        {
            cameraToMove.transform.DOMove(cameraProp.Camera.transform.position, cameraProp.timeToTravel)
                .SetEase(cameraProp.easeType);

            cameraToMove.transform.DORotateQuaternion(cameraProp.Camera.transform.rotation, cameraProp.timeToTravel)
                .SetEase(cameraProp.easeType);
        });

        mainSequence.Append(camSequence);
    }

    mainSequence.OnComplete(() =>
    {
        //on complete logic
        CameraStuffComplete("SEQUENCE COMPLETED");
    });
    
    mainSequence.Play();
}


Will this allow tweens to overlap eachother?

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think this specific implementation will allow overlap, I will take a look to see how to implement that now

have edited the original post, give it a try and hopefully it works

it seems like it doesn't start the tween.. Also, would there be a way to add a delay before each tween starts? but yea it didnt start the tweens.. I'm still kinda new to this and stuff so idk how it works lol
